# How to call other service from one service response in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("myservice").then(function (response) {
        $scope.studentdata = response.data;
    });
});
```

Based on student data i need to call other service like student address.how to achieve i am new to angular js please help.

Comment: Please post code of your service

Comment: [chain them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34761855/how-to-chain-multiple-http-calls-in-angular?rq=1) together, since there is a dependancy. e.g. `$http.post("other_service", $scope.studentdata).then(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use promise chains to call the request after another

```
    function firstReq(){
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost/api/users',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            data: JSON.stringify($scope.user)
        })
    }

    function secondReq(){
       return $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url : 'http://localhost/api/users/' +$scope.user_id + '/accessTokens',
       })
    }

    $scope.processform = function() {
         firstReq()
           .then( function( response )
            {
                console.log(response.data.user_id);
                $scope.user_id = response.data.user_id;
                return secondReq();
            })
            .then(function(response){
               console.log(response.data);
            })
  }
```